# thymeleaf does not apply on the html

Tags: thymeleaf

I am currently trying to apply thymleaf on my HTML file.

But it does not apply on it.

pom.xml

[image: this is the pom.xml. I added thymeleaf]

html file
[image: this is the html file]

where i stored the html
[image: this is where my html file is]

result
[image]

I am trying to figure out for hours But I can't find the reason.

Is there something I missed?

Please help THank you!

Comment: Each Thymeleaf expression needs to be placed _inside_ its related tag as an HTML _attribute_ (not as literal string content): `<td th:text="${grade.name}"></td>`. Look at any example in the [official documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#standard-expression-syntax).

Comment: Also for future reference, take a look at why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question.